# Map eastings in QGIS 2:18 Print Composer alternate between correct values, then negative values

Tags: coordinates, qgis-3, qgis-print-layouts

Using CRS OSGB 1936 (ESPG 4277) at various map scales in Composer, I find that the northings are all correct, but the eastings alternate between two or three correct values, then two negative ones.

I upgraded to version 3.2.2. The problem still exists.

Comment: [EPSG:4277](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/osgb-1936/) is the datum for OS National Grid and is **not** the projected CRS.  can you clarify that you intend this, or should you be using [EPSG:27700](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/osgb-1936-british-national-grid/) instead?

Comment: The unit of EPSG 4277 is degrees, not meters.

Comment: You were correct @JimT, there are two confusingly similar OSGB 1936 CRS's. EPSG:27700 is the correct one, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Summarized from the comments (which appear to have solved the issue):

[EPSG 4277](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/osgb-1936/) is the geographic coordinate system *OSGB 1936*.  In reality this is little used except as an intermediary when converting ETRF89 latitude/longitude coordinates to/from the *Ordnance Survey National Grid* ([EPSG 27700](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/osgb-1936-british-national-grid/)), which is the projected coordinate system for Great Britain (also commonly known as British National Grid, and also confusingly known as 'OSGB 36').

[EPSG 4277](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/osgb-1936/) has units degrees.

[EPSG 27700](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/osgb-1936-british-national-grid/) has units metres and is the CRS code to use for the OS Grid.

Further information may be found in [A Guide to Coordinate
Systems in Great Britain](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/docs/support/guide-coordinate-systems-great-britain.pdf).